What is the difference between ion weapons and EMP weapons in Star Wars?
Star Wars originally established that the weapons used to disable the electronic systems of droids and (on a larger scale) starships were called ion weapons, presumably working by shooting a stream of ions at the target. This is the same effect EMP (electromagnetic pulse) weapons have. Yet, Star Wars also mentions EMP weapons separately from ion weapons.
Examples:

Electro Magnetic Pulse grenade

EP-750X EMP missile launcher


Is there a difference or are these just colloquial, interchangeable terms? I haven't a clue what would happen if you shot a beam of ions at something, but honestly, it sounds far more advanced than an EMP.
This proves you could combine them:

Empion mine

But how are they different, if at all?

EMP Missiles are not canon. They're from a licenced roleplaying game

EMPion Mines are also non-canon. They're from a Legends novel from the 1990s.

EMP is canon https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse#:~:text=An%20electromagnetic%20pulse%20(or%20EMP,Republic%20during%20the%20Clone%20Wars.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?
